# GCM errorCode = NotRegistered

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app that uses GCM technology. I am trying to send a push notification from my server built on Java (Eclipse) with the token ("cX1gcdNYiQQ:APA91bE4...")
of the user that registered to my app that was saved in my database.
When I try to send a notification to the user, it says 
"errorCode = NotRegistered". I tried to delete the token and registered again but it's still giving me this error, always this error nothing else.
I am running the app through USB cable to my smartphone (LG). 
What should I do to fix this, what did I do wrong?

**Server code:**

```
    package jdbc;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.sound.midi.SysexMessage;

import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

public class GcmSender {
     private static final int GCM_RETRIES = 0;

    public void sendGooglePushNotification(String token, String type, String      
     data) {

        // Create Message
    Message.Builder builder = new Message.Builder().delayWhileIdle(true);

    try {
        builder.addData(Params.TYPE_MESSAGE, URLEncoder.encode(type, "UTF-       
       8"));
        builder.addData(Params.DATA_MESSAGE, URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-
   8"));
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e1.printStackTrace();
        }

       Message gcm_message = builder.build();

       // Create Sender
        Sender sender = new Sender(Params.GCM_SERVER_KEY);

         // Sending Message with Sender to the list of users.
        try {

           Result rs=sender.send(gcm_message, token, GCM_RETRIES);
           String ans=rs.toString();
            System.out.println(ans);

            //System.out.println("notification sent");
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           // Failed to Send Message.

       }

   }
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.world.bolandian.watchme"
     android:installLocation="preferExternal">

     <!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
     <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user.
              This disconnect
      option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer 
   policies
     -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- [END gcm_permission] -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.MainActivity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!--
    <activity
        android:name="."
        android:label="@string/title_activity_register" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.Register" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.default" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    -->
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.Login" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <!--
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false"></service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
        android:value="true"/>
</application>
```

**And this is the listener code in the Android App (downloaded from google developers website)**

```
package com.world.bolandian.watchme;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent; 
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService;

public class MyGcmListenerService extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = "MyGcmListenerService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param from SenderID of the sender.
 * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
 *             For Set of keys use data.keySet().
 */
// [START receive_message]
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("gcm_message");
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message: " + message);

    if (from.startsWith("/topics/")) {
        // message received from some topic.
    } else {
        // normal downstream message.
    }

    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    /**
     * Production applications would usually process the message here.
     * Eg: - Syncing with server.
     *     - Store message in local database.
     *     - Update UI.
     */

    /**
     * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating to 
   the user
     * that a message was received.
     */
    sendNotification(message);
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END receive_message]

   /**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received GCM message.
 *
 * @param message GCM message received.
 */
    private void sendNotification(String message) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /*          Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

      Uri defaultSoundUri =      RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
      NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new No    tificationCompat.Builder(this)
            //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Message")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: replace to GCM_RETRIES = "more than one"

Comment: what do you mean "more than one"?

Comment: due to network issue some time request become failed for first time so try this : GCM_RETRIES = "1" or GCM_RETRIES = "2"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approch..

```
    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->
        <permission
        android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchmek.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
        <uses-permission android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />



        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.world.bolandian.watchme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

You can check your server end programming is right or not.
 [here](http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/) (check your push notification with register token id and api key)

[Not Register](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream) comes due to following problem.

1. If the client app unregisters with GCM. If the client app is
   automatically unregistered, which can happen
2. if the user uninstalls
       the application. For example, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service
       reported the APNS token as invalid.
3. If the registration token expires (for example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens, or the APNS token has expired for iOS devices).
4. If the client app is updated but the new version is not configured to
       receive messages.

**then, Firstly You can check your API key. and regenerate token or register id from device after that check with testing server. [here](http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/) (with GCM Field Only) or [here](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/gcm.html)**

for help **you can follow [this link](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/).**

I hope this will help you. thanks

Sorry for My english

Comment: i have tried to check my push notification in the website that you gave me. in the **Result Output: Success**. but when i run the same device token on my server it still gives me **errorcode = notRegistered**. do you have any idea what causes it?

Comment: Firstly,you have push notification or not with another test server?

Comment: If you find push notification on device then your client side coding is fine . problem in server end coding.

Comment: I think, problem in your server api key used in server end..check now

Comment: https://github.com/hmkcode/Android/blob/master/java-post-gcm/src/main/java/com/hmkcode/POST2GCM.java.. or follow this link also..

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates that the mobile device is not registered with GCM Server.
There can be possible errors :

1. check the project number with which the device register.
   i.e. `regId = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);`
   the project number and the Api key used in server should correspond to same
   project.
2. Check the registration id sent to GCM server in gcm/send request.
   It should match with the registration id of mobile (Get the id from mobile
   logs : match it properly with the id used in server)
3. If nothing works, try to send gcm request using curl request.

   curl --header "Authorization:key=API_KEY" --header  Content
       Type:"application/json"  https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send  -d
       "{\"data\" : {\"Message\":\"Welcome to push notifications\"}
       \"registration_ids\":[\"regId\"] }"

If the curl request works, then the server is having some problem and if it does not then check the mobile app registration step.